# Under what kinds of circumstances would I want to run a short (non-zero) delay for a settimeout call in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am currently learning JavaScript and I understand that setTimeout pushes a function call through the browser APIs to the queue (once the timeout has expired), after which the event loop will put the function back on the stack once the stack has been cleared.  If I understand correctly, the relative ordering of the queue will have to do with the lengths of the timeouts of callbacks, as well as the duration of any intervening functions.

In the below code

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Hello"); }, 3000);
foo(); \\Some function of finite duration
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("World"); }, 3000);
```

I would expect the printout to be--

```
Hello 
World
```

--regardless of the duration of foo().

And for the below code with unequal timeouts

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Hello"); }, 5000);
foo(); \\Some function of finite duration
setTimeout(function(){ console.log("World"); }, 3000);
```

I believe that the console could display either--

```
Hello
World
```

--or--

```
World
Hello
```

--depending on the duration of foo()

So my real question is the following: If my callback is going to wait until the stack is clear anyway, and I want to ensure that my script runs as efficiently as possible, why wouldn't I just use

```
setTimeout(function(){bar();},0);
```

for most of my callbacks? I can avoid callbacks being reordered in the queue and they will run as soon as possible after the stack is clear. Is there any benefit in general to calling some short finite non-zero timeout length, like 5ms for example?

Comment: Environments generally enforce a minimum timer duration anyway, usually 15ms or so.

Comment: In my experience you should generally avoid using a timeout in the core logic, it's generally used more for UI interaction, where the the return order is rarely important. (It's still worth understanding, but I wouldn't worry about optimising your use of timeouts)

Answer (score 0):

Queueing occurs also on timeout set to 0. It means "soon ass possible". Shorter timing does not means that the timing will be exactly as set.
Timeout timing is [not reliable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)